# How to transform the list to dictionary in C# using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have data like below

```
        var listOfForm= new List<FormType>()
        {
                new FormType() {  Page = 1, Type = "FORM-K4"},
                new FormType() {  Page = 2, Type = "OTHER-FORM"},
                new FormType() {  Page = 3, Type = "OTHER-FORM"},
                new FormType() {  Page = 4, Type = "FORM-K5"},
                new FormType() {  Page = 5, Type = "OTHER-FORM"},
                new FormType() {  Page = 6, Type = "OTHER-FORM"},
                new FormType() {  Page = 7, Type = "OTHER-FORM"},
                new FormType() {  Page = 8, Type = "FORM-K6"},
                new FormType() {  Page = 9, Type = "OTHER_FORM"},
                new FormType() {  Page = 10, Type = "FORM-K7"},
                new FormType() {  Page = 11, Type = "FORM-K7"},
                new FormType() {  Page = 12, Type = "OTHER_FORM"},
        };
```

I want to create a dictionary. I want to add these two OTHER-FORM after FORM-K4 to the dictionary where the key is FORM-K4 and the rest of the list got the same pattern, added the OTHER-FORM to the type/key that was detected before.

for example, there are three Other-form after form-k5, so I want add each Page form these other-form to form-k5 key.

```
var dictForm = dictionary<Type, List<Page>>
```

so when I access dictForm.key form-k5 it will return value 4,5,6,7 and when the key is form-k4 value is 1,2,3.

Comment: Please edit your question to show expected output in code.

Comment: very hard to understand what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own extension method to transform the data into a dictionary, as this has custom rules.

**Code**

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<string, List<int>> ToDictionary(this IEnumerable<FormType> formTypes)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<int>> output = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
        string currentType = string.Empty;

        foreach (var formType in formTypes)
        {
            if (formType.Type.StartsWith("FORM") && formType.Type != currentType)
            {
                currentType = formType.Type;

                if (!output.ContainsKey(currentType))
                {
                    output.Add(currentType, new List<int>());
                }
            }

            
            output[currentType].Add(formType.Page);
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> output = listOfForm
    .ToDictionary();
```

**Output**

```
FORM-K4 : 1, 2, 3
FORM-K5 : 4, 5, 6, 7
FORM-K6 : 8, 9
FORM-K7 : 10, 11, 12
```